# Perforce: How to branch a special version?

Tags: branch, perforce

To create a working version, I've reverted MAIN with a Changelist number, updated some directory to HEAD version, also added some new files and folders. All new files, folders have been committed to perforce.
I want to create a snapshot of current workspace. Since current workspace contains many special changes, not sure how to create a branch of current working code without missing anything?

Current workspace structure:

> ~/workspace/some_are_old_changelist_xxx
>   ~/workspace/some_are_head
>   ~/workspace/some_are_new_added_files_folders

Depot structure:

> //depot/MAIN/...

Want to branch current workspace to:

> //depot/DEV/1.0/...

Answer (score 0):

To branch from the revision you currently have in your workspace use the `#have` revision specifier for the source revision range:

```
p4 integrate //depot/MAIN/...#have //depot/dev/fisher/special/...
p4 submit
```

Since you didn't give any details about your environment I'm assuming you're using a "classic" depot and have a default client view that maps the whole thing.  The steps/syntax are slightly different if you have a streams depot or a focused client view (you'd need to create a new stream spec and/or update your client) but the semantics are basically the same -- the key thing is that you want to branch from `#have` rather than the default `#head`.

Comment: Tried command: run "p4 integrate //depot/MAIN/...#have //depot/DEV/special/..." in workspace root folder, but get message "File(s) not in client view.".

Comment: This is the type of thing I was talking about in the second paragraph.  Sounds like you need to update your client view to map the new branch!  If you're not sure how to do that, recommend posting a new question that includes `p4 client -o` output along with your error message.

Comment: or you could edit this question to include more context about your environment (again, `p4 client -o`, maybe the actual name of the new branch you want to create -- I just made up `//depot/dev/fisher/special`)

Comment: I've added some details. Please let me know if you need more info.